# BASH - is it possible to check memory usage of command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check **how much resources took each command** in my script

*example code*

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/{1..100}
touch /tmp/{1..100}
```

I want to know what resource was taken by mkdir and what by touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command **perf**, and it's really complete.

**Intall** it with those 2 commands:

`sudo apt install linux-tools-common`

`sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-47-generic`

```
test@test:~/work$ sudo perf stat ls
  perf.data

 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

              0.83 msec task-clock                #    0.793 CPUs utilized          
                 2      context-switches          #    0.002 M/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               113      page-faults               #    0.136 M/sec                  
   <not supported>      cycles                                                      
   <not supported>      instructions                                                
   <not supported>      branches                                                    
   <not supported>      branch-misses                                               

       0.001051057 seconds time elapsed

       0.000989000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

- This my repository

```sh
test@test:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

- My distribution

```sh
test@test:~$ uname -a
Linux test 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please can you share your repository? ```(/etc/apt/sources.list)```

I am unable to find this package

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-common
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-47-generic
`